# Pause wget and resume when closing terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, wget, ubuntu-server

I've searched all over the web and have come to the conclusion that it's possible to pause **wget** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and that it's possible to resume with *wget -c [URI]* But what I haven't found is whether it's the same if I'm mirroring a server over ftp:

```
wget -m ftp://user:pass@server/directory
```

will I also be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> pause the download and resume later with just:

```
wget -c ftp://user:pass@server/directory
```

or do I have to add the -m parameter when resuming?

The main thing I don't yet understand though is: whether the download can be resumed even after I've closed the terminal and re-logged in later? (I'm currently in the server over ssh with bitwise)

The best scenario I would be looking for is for me to be able to pause the download (It's a huge download and I don't want to lose any progress I've made so far) and somehow resume it in the background, so when I close the terminal, it will still finish the download. If so, will I later somehow have to stop the process manually or it will end itself when the download is done?

Thank you for all and any help!

Best regards,

Alari

Comment: If you send a ctrl+c to the wget you actually killing the process not pausing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on some remote server and want to disconnect your terminal whilst continuing the download, just run it in the background with 'nohup' and '&':

```
$ nohup wget -q url & 
$ exit
```

The download will continue. Or consider using a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen so you can track its progress.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For this, do I have to start the download over from scratch?

Comment: Not necessarily, if it's already running you can pause it with ctrl-z, then run ``bg %1`` to continue to run it in the background, then run ``disown`` so the shell won't close background processes, and then ``exit`` the shell.

Comment: But I'd recommend you look into ``tmux`` too.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has given me a more clear insight!

Comment: disown was not pre-installed on my distro (lakka) so i had to cancel and restart the download.